# Release a Startpage in MVC .4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

(Note: I'm a total beginner in the ASP.NET MVC World...)
Environment: Visual Studio 2012
Project Application: ASP.NET MVC 4.0

I did set /views/home/index.html as startpage...  Things didn't turn out as I wanted and I can't debug.
Error Message says:

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
```

---

Now I wonder how do I regret this move... I even don't know which file that was set as the startup page to begin with…

Which file is usually the default startup file?
Can I release a file from being “The StartUp Page”?
I also have an older version on another computer. Environment Vs 2010. Can I see there which file that is setup to be the start page?

I'm grateful for any kind of hint or solution to solve my task…  Thank you.  Hope this info is enough for you to understand my issue. If not I’ll try to make it more easy to understand.

**Solution used after the answers below:
I chose "yourprojectname-properties" in the "Project menu". Then chose "Web" in the properties window. then added / as mentioned above... To all of you that spent some time on this issue of mine... YOU ROCK! There Is No Tomorrow...**

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a route-url as starturl, not a page.
In ASP.NET MVC you have to work with routes and every route is mapped to an action.

Comment: I choosed "yourprojectname-properties" in the "Project menu". Then choosed "Web" in the properties window. 
then added / as mentioned above...
To all of you that spent some time on this issue of mine...       YOU ROCK!  
There Is No Tomorrow...